# How to create an Apache Beam Pipeline in Scala programming language?

Tags: scala, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to implement Apache Beam in Scala. To do that, I took a simple task of loading a file from my local(windows) and getting a word count.
This is what I wrote.

```
object ReadFromFile {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    PipelineOptionsFactory.register(Class[MyOptions])
    val options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args: _*).withValidation()  .as(classOf[MyOptions])
    val pipeline = Pipeline.create(options)
    pipeline.apply("ReadFiles", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractWords))
            .apply(Count.perElement())
            .apply(MapElements.via(new FormatResult))
            .apply("WriteWords", TextIO.write().to(options.getOutput))
    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()
  }
}
```

This is the rest of my setup. I followed the beam documentation from here to create an interface to implement get & set methods to read input file and create an output file.

```
trait MyOptions extends PipelineOptions{
  @Description("Path of the file to read from")
  @Default.String("path_of_input_file.txt")
  def getInputFile: String
  def setInputFile(path: String)

  @Description("Path of the file to write to")
  @Required
  def getOutput: String
  def setOutput(path: String)
}
```

and other UDFs to load, split & count the records.

```
class ExtractWords extends DoFn[String, String] {
  @ProcessElement
  def processElement(c: ProcessContext): Unit = {
    for (word <- c.element().split(",")) yield {
      if (word.nonEmpty) c.output(word)
    }
  }
}

class FormatResult extends SimpleFunction[KV[String, java.lang.Long], String] {
  override def apply(input: KV[String, java.lang.Long]): String = {
    input.getKey + ": " + input.getValue
  }
}

class CountWords extends PTransform[PCollection[String], PCollection[KV[String, java.lang.Long]]] {
  override def expand(input: PCollection[String]): PCollection[KV[String, lang.Long]] = {
    input.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractWords)) //Ignore IntelliJ error: "Cannot resolve apply". The code will compile.
      .apply(Count.perElement())
  }
}
```

But I am seeing a compilation error in my main class on the apply method at getting the count: `.apply(Count.perElement())`
which says:

> Cannot resolve overloaded method 'apply'

This is my project structure and the same error could be seen in the image:
[image]

This is the first time I am learning Apache Beam. Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I did here and how can I fix the error ?

Comment: Is the error real? **IntelliJ** is (in)famous for having a lot of false error messages. Try compiling the code with **sbt**, **maven** or whatever build tool you are using to see if it is replicable. - BTW, take a look to [**scio**](https://github.com/spotify/scio).

Comment: Well, I didn't try to build the project. Since this is the first time I am working with Beam, I thought there is something wrong with the code I wrote.

Comment: Could you try that out? I don't see anything wrong with your code at first glance. If you're using Scala, you might be interested in https://spotify.github.io/scio/ as well.